# react native render another component in main

Tags: react-native, render, react-navigation, tabnavigator

i want to render another component in the main component so user won't face a white screen for a second!
i'm using TabNavigator from react-navigation and when i want to switch between tabs, i face a white screen for a second (seems it need a second to render).
i was thinking of rendering the second tab in the first so i can have a better user experience!
P.s. : my components are in separate files!

**Main:**

```
export default class AdCalc extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          TEST
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**and my child:**

```
export default class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>
          This is child!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react-navigation TabNavigatorConfig's lazy prop. Pass lazy={false} so that your views may load at initial start. Then you will not see such a screen.