# How to render child element in parent element from event handler in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, createelement

I am creating a country autocomplete code in React JS.

The idea is that whenever use types in the search bar, the onInput event will occur. Then it will filter the countries by checking the input against the array elements i.e all countries.

When I console.log() the filtered array, I get the exact result which I am looking for, but the problem is I want to create a child element `<div></div>` and append it to the parent element.

But the code I use to render the child element isn't working. I tried to use the appendChild() but that too isn't working.

Here is my code for the parent component.

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchLocationBarItem from './SearchLocationBarItem';

class SearchLocationBar extends React.Component {
    countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua &amp; Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks &amp; Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
    selectedCountries = [];

    handleOnInput = (e) => {
        let element =  undefined;
        this.selectedCountries = this.countries.filter((country) => {
            if(country.startsWith(e.target.value)){
                React.render(<SearchLocationBarItem item={country} />, document.getElementById('autocomplete'));
            }
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form autoComplete="off" method="post">
                <div id="custom-search-input">
                    <div className="input-group ">
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            className=" search-query" 
                            placeholder="Your Address or postal code"
                            onInput={this.handleOnInput} 
                        />
                        <div id="autocomplete" className="autocomplete-items">

                        </div>
                        <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <input type="submit" className="btn_search" value="submit" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchLocationBar;
```

And the code for child component.

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
    return (
        <div>{props.item}</div>
    );
}
```

I tried to go through the React doc and google but I was not able to get the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460337/react-native-render-another-component-in-main)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your `selectedContries` in state and in render you can iterate your component like that.

```
import React from "react";
import SearchLocationBarItem from "./SearchLocationBarItem";

class SearchLocationBar extends React.Component {
  countries = [
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Anguilla",
    "Antigua &amp; Barbuda",
    "Argentina",
    "Armenia",
    "Aruba",
    "Australia",
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Bahamas",
    "Bahrain",
    "Bangladesh",
    "Barbados",
    "Belarus",
    "Belgium",
    "Belize",
    "Benin",
    "Bermuda",
    "Bhutan",
    "Bolivia",
    "Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina",
    "Botswana",
    "Brazil",
    "British Virgin Islands",
    "Brunei",
    "Bulgaria",
    "Burkina Faso",
    "Burundi",
    "Cambodia",
    "Cameroon",
    "Canada",
    "Cape Verde",
    "Cayman Islands",
    "Central Arfrican Republic",
    "Chad",
    "Chile",
    "China",
    "Colombia",
    "Congo",
    "Cook Islands",
    "Costa Rica",
    "Cote D Ivoire",
    "Croatia",
    "Cuba",
    "Curacao",
    "Cyprus",
    "Czech Republic",
    "Denmark",
    "Djibouti",
    "Dominica",
    "Dominican Republic",
    "Ecuador",
    "Egypt",
    "El Salvador",
    "Equatorial Guinea",
    "Eritrea",
    "Estonia",
    "Ethiopia",
    "Falkland Islands",
    "Faroe Islands",
    "Fiji",
    "Finland",
    "France",
    "French Polynesia",
    "French West Indies",
    "Gabon",
    "Gambia",
    "Georgia",
    "Germany",
    "Ghana",
    "Gibraltar",
    "Greece",
    "Greenland",
    "Grenada",
    "Guam",
    "Guatemala",
    "Guernsey",
    "Guinea",
    "Guinea Bissau",
    "Guyana",
    "Haiti",
    "Honduras",
    "Hong Kong",
    "Hungary",
    "Iceland",
    "India",
    "Indonesia",
    "Iran",
    "Iraq",
    "Ireland",
    "Isle of Man",
    "Israel",
    "Italy",
    "Jamaica",
    "Japan",
    "Jersey",
    "Jordan",
    "Kazakhstan",
    "Kenya",
    "Kiribati",
    "Kosovo",
    "Kuwait",
    "Kyrgyzstan",
    "Laos",
    "Latvia",
    "Lebanon",
    "Lesotho",
    "Liberia",
    "Libya",
    "Liechtenstein",
    "Lithuania",
    "Luxembourg",
    "Macau",
    "Macedonia",
    "Madagascar",
    "Malawi",
    "Malaysia",
    "Maldives",
    "Mali",
    "Malta",
    "Marshall Islands",
    "Mauritania",
    "Mauritius",
    "Mexico",
    "Micronesia",
    "Moldova",
    "Monaco",
    "Mongolia",
    "Montenegro",
    "Montserrat",
    "Morocco",
    "Mozambique",
    "Myanmar",
    "Namibia",
    "Nauro",
    "Nepal",
    "Netherlands",
    "Netherlands Antilles",
    "New Caledonia",
    "New Zealand",
    "Nicaragua",
    "Niger",
    "Nigeria",
    "North Korea",
    "Norway",
    "Oman",
    "Pakistan",
    "Palau",
    "Palestine",
    "Panama",
    "Papua New Guinea",
    "Paraguay",
    "Peru",
    "Philippines",
    "Poland",
    "Portugal",
    "Puerto Rico",
    "Qatar",
    "Reunion",
    "Romania",
    "Russia",
    "Rwanda",
    "Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon",
    "Samoa",
    "San Marino",
    "Sao Tome and Principe",
    "Saudi Arabia",
    "Senegal",
    "Serbia",
    "Seychelles",
    "Sierra Leone",
    "Singapore",
    "Slovakia",
    "Slovenia",
    "Solomon Islands",
    "Somalia",
    "South Africa",
    "South Korea",
    "South Sudan",
    "Spain",
    "Sri Lanka",
    "St Kitts &amp; Nevis",
    "St Lucia",
    "St Vincent",
    "Sudan",
    "Suriname",
    "Swaziland",
    "Sweden",
    "Switzerland",
    "Syria",
    "Taiwan",
    "Tajikistan",
    "Tanzania",
    "Thailand",
    "Timor L'Este",
    "Togo",
    "Tonga",
    "Trinidad &amp; Tobago",
    "Tunisia",
    "Turkey",
    "Turkmenistan",
    "Turks &amp; Caicos",
    "Tuvalu",
    "Uganda",
    "Ukraine",
    "United Arab Emirates",
    "United Kingdom",
    "United States of America",
    "Uruguay",
    "Uzbekistan",
    "Vanuatu",
    "Vatican City",
    "Venezuela",
    "Vietnam",
    "Virgin Islands (US)",
    "Yemen",
    "Zambia",
    "Zimbabwe"
  ];
  state = {
    selectedCountries: []
  };
  handleOnInput = e => {
    let element = undefined;
    const filterdCountries = [];
    this.countries.map(country => {
      if (country.startsWith(e.target.value)) {
        filterdCountries.push(country);
      }
    });
    this.setState({
      selectedCountries: filterdCountries
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form autoComplete="off" method="post">
        <div id="custom-search-input">
          <div className="input-group ">
            <input
              type="text"
              className=" search-query"
              placeholder="Your Address or postal code"
              onInput={this.handleOnInput}
            />
            <div id="autocomplete" className="autocomplete-items">
              {this.state.selectedCountries.length &&
                this.state.selectedCountries.map((country, index) => (
                  <SearchLocationBarItem key={index} item={country} />
                ))}
            </div>
            <span className="input-group-btn">
              <input type="submit" className="btn_search" value="submit" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchLocationBar;
```

Comment: Thanks man, I completely ignored state and thought there might be some other way to append the child component, but this was best solution